# How to use array variables as defined variables in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I declared an array

```
$CLISTS=array("Add_Product"=>"products.php","Payment_Type"=>"payment.php","Shipping"=>"shipping.php");
```

and I defined variables

```
<?php 
define("Add_Product",TRUE);
define("Payment_Type",FALSE);
define("Shipping",FALSE);


foreach($CLISTS as $lists=>$page)
{
if($lists==TRUE)
{
?>
<div class='alert' style="text-decoration:line-through;"><?php echo str_replace("_"," ",$lists);?></div>
<?php }
else
{   
?>
<div class='alert'><a href="<?php echo $page;?>"><?php echo str_replace("_"," ",$lists);?></a></div>

<?php }
} 
?>
```

Its not working. All the div is strikes. What I did mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFINE` does not do what you think it does. [Define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) creates a [named constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

And you cannot change your array variables with it.

Simply do:

```
$CLISTS['Add_Product'] = true;
$CLISTS['Payment_Type'] = false;
$CLISTS['Shipping'] = false;
```

To change your array variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the logic like

```
foreach($CLISTS as $lists=>$page)
{
    if($lists == 'Add_Product')
    {
?>
```

Or even you can use `===` like

```
foreach($CLISTS as $lists=>$page)
{
    if($lists === TRUE)
    {
?>
```